# Appending text to an edit control running out of room?

Tags: c++, c, windows

So here is my problem, it works fine until it reaches a certain amount of data. I can't show a whole html file for example that is about 1MB in the window it gets cut off.

Window:

```
case WM_CREATE:

    hEdit = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "EDIT", "", 
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | ES_READONLY | WS_HSCROLL | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_AUTOHSCROLL, 
        0, 0, 100, 100, hWnd, (HMENU)IDC_MAIN_EDIT, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    if(hEdit == NULL)
        MessageBox(hWnd, "Could not create edit box.", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);

    hfDefault = (HFONT)GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT);
    SendMessage(hEdit, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hfDefault, MAKELPARAM(FALSE, 0));
    LogText(hEdit,logstring);
    break;
```

Function:

```
void LogText(HWND hEdit, const char * logstring)
{
const char * logstring2="\r\n";
int iLength = GetWindowTextLength(hEdit);
SendMessage(hEdit, EM_SETSEL, iLength, iLength);
SendMessage(hEdit, EM_REPLACESEL, 0, (LPARAM) logstring);
SendMessage(hEdit, WM_VSCROLL, SB_BOTTOM, (LPARAM)NULL);
int iLength2 = GetWindowTextLength(hEdit);
SendMessage(hEdit, EM_SETSEL, iLength2, iLength2);
SendMessage(hEdit, EM_REPLACESEL, 0, (LPARAM) logstring2);
SendMessage(hEdit, WM_VSCROLL, SB_BOTTOM, (LPARAM)NULL);

}
```

Usage:

```
 logstring="Test";
LogText(hEdit, logstring);
```

Like I said, it works perfect, except it stops working after its spit out an unknown amount of data which I've noticed is a very consistent number.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the upper limit with [`EM_LIMITTEXT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761607.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the text limit of an edit box with the [EM_SETLIMITTEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761647%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message.  Just define the upper limit before you attempt to assign text to the edit box.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I used. I just sent this message in WM_CREATE.

Comment: SendMessage(hEdit,EM_SETLIMITTEXT,100000000,0);